# How to customize the scroller on ios devices

Tags: ios, css, iphone

I am creating an application in ios and want to customize the default scroller on my site.Can u please suggest me how to customize the scroller style.I want the scroller like android device. Is it possible.

Comment: what do you want to change? the looks? the behaviour? i would highly recommend not changing anything - why are people always trying to change the default user experience? It will just feel and look odd and wrong.

Comment: I want it running on touch only and display a slim scroller at corner

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to target an iOS devices scrollbar specifically, unless you wanted to do it through a media query in which I guess that would work.

However CSSTricks have an article that should answer your code related questions on how to.

Source: https://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/

Comment: I want to customize the style of scroller not like overflow and all.

Comment: I understood that. If you look at the 'Very Simple Example' within the source you'll see how to style it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to customize the scrollers the only way to do it is to dig through the UIScrollView hierarchy and manipulate it there (it's just a UIView at the end of the day). This will probably lead to the app getting rejected, or the code breaking randomly in the future since it's undocumented and Apple can just change it whenever they want.

I had to do this once for a client (they insisted, I argued, they were paying so they won) and ended up just completely reimplementing the scroller in a subview of UIScrollView. Basically, you add your own custom UIView to be the scroller, then manipulate it using the UIScrollViewDelegate callbacks to manipulate the size and placement of the view as a percentage scrolled. Depending on the complexity and time you can get really accurate.